# Finding all class names used in HTML/DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

How can I get a list of all class names used inside an HTML Snippet?

For example, the HTML Snippet below,

```
<div class="name">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="last"></div>
</div>
```

would have output `name`, `first`, `last` or `name`, `name > first`, `name > last`. Here, I am concerned about finding all class selectors first. Nesting could be optional.

I expect to use Javascript or Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 16):

Get all the elements in the document using `querySelectorAll`, then loop through them, getting each one's class, breaking it apart on spaces, and adding new ones to an `allClasses` array:

```js
var allClasses = [];

var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*');

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
  var classes = allElements[i].className.toString().split(/\s+/);
  for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
    var cls = classes[j];
    if (cls && allClasses.indexOf(cls) === -1)
      allClasses.push(cls);
  }
}

console.log(allClasses);
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar baz"></div>
</div>
```

To get the classnames in only one part of the document, specify that in the `querySelectorAll` call:

```
var allElements = document.getElementById('my-elt').querySelectorAll('*');
```

#### Modern approach

Using ES6, we can write this more functionally as:

```
[].concat(                            // concatenate
  ...[...                             // an array of
    document.querySelectorAll('*')    // all elements
  ] .
    map(                              // mapping each 
      elt =>                          // element
        [...                          // to the array of
          elt.classList               // its classes
        ]
    )
);
```

Or, as a one liner:

```
[].concat(...[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].map(elt => [...elt.classList]));
```

Then you will want to apply `uniq` to the result. You can write that yourself, or use Underscore's `_.uniq` etc. Here's a simple one for use here:

```
function unique(array) {
  var prev;
  return array.sort().filter(e => e !== prev && (prev = e));
}
```

Comment: would `document.querySelectorAll('[class]')` be any faster?

Comment: @dandavis Quite possibly.

Answer (score 6):

## Simple ES10 new Set() approach

```
const allClasses = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[class]')).flatMap(e => e.className.toString().split(/\s+/))
const classes = new Set()

allClasses.forEach(c => classes.add(c))

console.log(classes)
```

Get all the class names and split on space so for example, "child first" would become 'child' and 'first'. If you don't like this behaviour you can remove the toString and split functions.

Then add every class name to the set. There is no need to check for duplicates since the set does that for us. If you do want to store duplicates you can use a Map instead.

Answer (score 6):

Piggybacking off of the one-liner from @user1679669 and @Nermin's answer using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), you can get a list of all the classes on a page with this one-liner:

```js
const allClasses = [...new Set([].concat(...[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].map(elt => [...elt.classList])))];
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner that returns unique class names in alphabetical order, the query part based on @torazaburo's answer:

```
[].concat(...[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].map(e=>[...e.classList])).filter((d,i,a)=>a.indexOf(d)==i).sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like the snippet below, it uses jQuery but that's just easier to read imo, a Javascript version wouldn't be much harder I'd assume.

Basically you want to get all of the `nodes`, then add all of the unique classes to a list..

This is **much** harder to implement if you're looking for dynamic classes which may be applied with Javascript.

Nesting would require more insight as to how it should be performed, how to handle dupe classes but not dupe class arrays and similar..

*If this get's downvoted because of the jQuery I'll be upset.*

```js
var classes = [];

$('body *:not(script)').each(function(){
  _classes = $(this).attr('class') ? $(this).attr('class').split(' ') : []
  _classes.forEach(function(entry){
    if(classes.indexOf(entry) < 0){
      classes.push(entry)
    }
  })
})

console.log(classes)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dog"></div>
<span class="dog cat"></span>
<div></div>
<blockquote class="bird"></blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is HTML:**

```
<div id="oye">
<div class="pop"></div>
<div class="hop"></div>
<div class="bob"></div>
</div>

<p id="my"></p>
```

In Jquery, You will get array of all class name, Check below code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var myclass = [];
  var parent = $("#oye");
    var divs = parent.children();

  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){

    myclass.push(divs[i].className)
  }

  //console.log(myclass);


  var myclasses = myclass.join(', ');

  $("#my").html(myclasses);


});
```

See Demo Here: https://codepen.io/ihemant360/pen/PzWJZP

Comment: Will this work if an element contains multiple classes? What about grandchildren?

Comment: Your solution is awesome. but read question, given a output example. So  I did according to that.

Comment: It is hardly a good solution to limit your answer to the specific example given by the OP, when he obviously (?) wants/needs to be able to handle multiple classes on elements, and multiple nesting levels.

Answer (score 0):

Correction to KR Thirto's reply:

```
const allClasses = new Set(
                 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("*"))
                .map( (el) => el.className )
                 );

const flatClasses = new Set(
            Array.from(allClasses)
            .map((el) => el.split(/\s+/g))
                        .flat(1)
            .filter((el) => el)
             );
```

First we map the classname property for all DOM nodes into a set. This classname property contains the actual classnames, separated by a space.

As split() returns an array, splitting the classname property within allClasses will result in an array where some elements are strings, and other elements are arrays containing the result of the split() operation on classname.

To flatten this array, the flat(1) method is used.
The filter() method needs to be applied to filter out undefined (empty string) classnames.

Answer (score -1):

Get all the classes & the unique ones in one dimension.

```js
const allClasses = Array.from(new Set(document.querySelectorAll("*").map(el => el.classNames)));

const flatClasses = Array.from(new Set(allClasses.flat(1)))
```