# How to find the frequencies of all class names in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the frequencies of all class names used in the DOM?

For example,

```js
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='child first'></div>
  <div class='child second'></div>
</div>
```

would give me perhaps an object, map or array with the output:

```js
result: {
  wrapper: 1,
  child:   2,
  first:   1,
  second:  1
}
```

---

So far I've used the devtools to inspect the DOM and see if I can find any class names that are used multiple times.

## Update 2021-08-24

I don't understand how this question could get closed due to "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center...". It may have had some issues, but it was *definitely* about programming. All I wanted was a script or something which could've helped me solve this problem.

Also, I understand you should usually try to solve it yourself and show your previous attempts, but I had absolutely no idea where to start. And, as I said, I already had done some manual attempts but they weren't sustainable.

In the end, I managed to solve it with the help of Jeremy (thanks). If the question gets opened again I will post my solution which was inspired and derived from Jeremy's.

Comment: It isn't really practical to do this. All that would tell you is how many times a class name showed up in a given page at a given time. Since they can be dynamically added and removed with JS, you can't count them in a general way safely.

Comment: what you can do is recurcively run through the DOM, but as Quentin said you won't get everything.
Also I downvoted because [you didn't attempt to do it by yourself](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually really curious to see how I might implement this, so I gave it a shot. Can probably be cleaned up, but should get you started.

I decided not to iterate through the DOM as that could be a recursive nightmare and instead opted for taking the page HTML as a string and using regex to extract the classes from elements.

```js
countClassFrequency = () => {
    const regex = /(class=['|"])([a-zA-Z\s-]*)(['|"])/g;
    let results = {};
    const html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    while ((match = regex.exec(html)) !== null) {
       let classes = match[2];
       classes = classes.split(' ');
       classes.forEach(c => {
          if (results[c]) {
             results[c]++;
          } else {
             results[c] = 1;
          }
       });
    }
    return results;
}

const output = countClassFrequency();

console.log(output);
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='child first'></div>
  <div class='child second'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy this really helped a lot!

Comment: With your inspiration and a little help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024631/finding-all-class-names-used-in-html-dom) question, I managed to create a pretty elegant solution if I may say so myself. I'll link to it here since I can't post any new answers.
https://jsfiddle.net/Nermin99/2La5m7vh/

Comment: Ah yeah, that looks much cleaner.